# Save data from R code

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I've adapted the example from spark slightly to work on an ec2 cluster
via hdfs. But I've only gotten the example to work with saving to
parquet files.

```
library(SparkR)

# Initialize SparkContext and SQLContext
sc <- sparkR.init()
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

# Create a simple local data.frame
localDF <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Smith", "Sarah"), age=c(19, 23, 18))

# Create a DataFrame from a JSON file
peopleDF <- jsonFile(sqlContext, file.path("/people.json"))

# Register this DataFrame as a table.
registerTempTable(peopleDF, "people")

# SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext
teenagers <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")

# Store the teenagers in a table
saveAsParquetFile(teenagers, file.path("/teenagers"))

# Stop the SparkContext now
sparkR.stop()
```

When I use `saveDF` instead of `saveAsParquetFile`, I get only get an
empty file in the hdfs.

```
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2015-07-23 15:14 /teenagers
```

How can I store my dataframe as text file (json/csv/...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spark 2.x**

In Spark 2.0 or later is built-in `csv` writer and there is no need for external dependencies:

```
write.df(teenagers, "teenagers", "csv", "error")
```

**Spark 1.x**

You can use [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv):

```
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS' = 
   '"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.1.0" "sparkr-shell"')
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

... # The rest of your code

write.df(teenagers, "teenagers", "com.databricks.spark.csv", "error")
```

In interactive mode you have start SparkR shell with `--packages`:

```
bin/sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.1.0
```